# JavaScript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a JavaScript array of string arrays: array1; array2 ; array3 which i need to break and then access the individual array. how can i do that?

Comment: can you show some code so that we can understand well what are you trying to work on... it quite confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `split` method:

```
var str = 'array1; array2 ; array3';
var arr = str.split('; ');
```

To access the individual array parts, you need to use index which starts from 0:

```
alert(arr[0]); // shows first item
alert(arr[1]); // shows second item
alert(arr[2]); // shows third item
```

Or you can loop through the array like this too:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: i think it's better if you split it with just ";", then just trim it.. so leading and trailing spaces will be omitted...

Comment: how can i access the elements in the array